# Как по заданному числу определить его 2-простоту?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, простые-числа, факторизация

> 2-простое число
>
> (Время: 1 сек. Память: 16 Мб Сложность: 28%)
>   Число называется 2-простым, если являются простыми числа, составленные из цифр этого числа в возрастающем и убывающем порядках.
>
> Требуется написать программу, которая по заданному числу определит его 2-простоту.
>
> Входные данные
>   Входной файл `INPUT.TXT` содержит натуральное число `N` (10 < N < 10<sup>9</sup>).
>
> Выходные данные
>   В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите сообщение «Yes», если число `N` является 2-простым и «No» - иначе.

Вот мой код:

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    using namespace std;
    int  i ,x,k, sum , n, re;
    int main()
    {
        cin >> n;
        if (n < 10) {
            re += 1;
        }
        for (int i = 2; i < n - 1; i++) {
            if (n%i == 0) {
                re += 1;
            }
        }
        string s = to_string(n);
        reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
        sum = atoi(s.c_str());
        for (int i = 2; i < sum - 1; i++) {
            if (sum % i == 0) {
                re += 1;
            }
        }
        if (re == 0) {
            cout << "Yes";
    }
    else {
        cout << "No";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Пишет что неправильно. В чем ошибка?

Comment: Как минимум, не вникая в логику, у Вас переменная `re` никак не инициализируется перед использованием.

Comment: @Yaant: Переменная `re` объявлена на уровне namespace, что означает, что она неявно инициализируется нулем.

Comment: @AnT А, вон оно как. Буду знать. :)

Comment: Нет, вы неверно мыслите. Это C++. Он определил адрес для переменной, и всё. Значение никто не просил менять. В ней лежит мусор

Answer (score 9, accepted):

У вас сам подход неверен.

Первое - вы просто обращаете порядок цифр числа, а нужно получить из вашего числа 2 других - ну, если у вас 173645, то это 134567 и 765431 ("*числа, составленные из цифр этого числа в возрастающем и убывающем порядках*").

Во-вторых, выполняя полный цикл при проверке на простоту, вы точно вылетите за пределы отпущенного времени. Достаточно проверки на делимость до квадратного корня из `n`...

Если вы хотите работать через строку - то получить два нужных числа можно

```
string s = to_string(n);
sort(s.begin(), s.end());
int n1 = stoi(s);
reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
int n2 = stoi(s);
```

Ну, а проверку на простоту я бы делал примерно так

```
bool isPrime(int n)
{
    if (n%2 == 0) return false;
    for(int i = 3; i*i <= n; i+=2)
        if (n%i==0) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: В очередной раз предлагаю минусатору :) объяснить, в чем я неправ.

Comment: там плюс а не минус

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Два плюса и один минус. Если нажать на цифру, показывается, сколько того и другого.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, хммм!.. спасибо, я даже не знал...

Comment: @Harry, все же не лучше определять простоту числа в компайл тайм?..

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Какого именно? 8-0